# Send a redirect after timeout in JSTL

Tags: jsp, redirect, jstl, jsp-tags

I use this script in my JSP to perform via timeout a redirect after 5 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect() {
        location.href = "registrazione.jsp";
    }
    window.setTimeout("redirect()", 5000);
</script>
```

I'm trying to eliminate any script in my web application. Is there a way to do this using JSTL or is there a specific tag library that I can download and use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that JSP/JSTL runs in webserver and that JavaScript runs in webbrowser.

In order to be able to send a redirect from the webserver, you need to have a HTTP response. In order to have a HTTP response, you have to retrieve a HTTP request. In order to have a HTTP request, the client has to send it somehow; by clicking a link, submitting a form, changing the URL in browser's address bar, executing JavaScript `window.location`, executing JavaScript `XMLHttpRequest`, etc.

In other words, you can't send a redirect using JSP/JSTL without that the client has sent a HTTP request in some way. So, it's end of story.

Your JavaScript approach is really the best you can get to achieve the concrete functional requirement. I do therefore not understand your aversion against it and that you need to replace it by JSP/JSTL. Are you sure that you aren't confusing "JSP *scriptlets*" with "JavaScript"? The former is indeed a [bad way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) of writing JSPs, but that's *definitely not* the same as JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I realized my misconception, it's all clear now!